# Necesito ejecutar una directiva dentro de un controlador angularjs

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

buenas tardes, tengo un problema, necesito llamar una directiva dentro de un método del controlador pero me sale el siguiente error: TypeError: Cannot create property 'directiveFunction' on string '0', no se que estoy haciendo mal, la siguiente porción de código hace parte del controlador donde llamo a la directiva.

```
if ($scope.count == "1") {  

            if ($scope.monto === null || $scope.monto.length === 0 || typeof $scope.monto === 'undefined'  ) {

                $scope.monto = (num);
            } else {

                $scope.monto = ($scope.monto + "" + num);

               // Llamada a la directiva
                $scope.dirOptions.directiveFunction();


            }
```

```js
 app.directive('blurToCurrency', function($filter){
  return {
    scope: {
      amount  : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      
      angular.extend(scope.amount,  {
    directiveFunction: function(){

        el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount,""));
  el.bind('focus', function(){
        el.val(scope.amount);
      });
      
      el.bind('input', function(){
        scope.amount = el.val();
        scope.$apply();
      });
      
      el.bind('blur', function(){
        el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount, ""));
      });
      

           
        },

       
      });

      

    }
  }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="col-sm-9 select">
   <label for="inlineFormInput" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input id="inlineFormInput" type="text" placeholder="Monto" blur-to-currency amount="monto"  size="4" ng-focus="count = 1" class="mx-sm-3 form-control">
                                    </div>
```

Comment: aun no has solucionado tu problema?

Comment: @TheVicious No, aun no

Comment: Si pudieras ayudarme te agradecería demasiado, aun estoy con ese problema

Comment: tienes directiveFunction en un controlador y lo estas llamando no?

Comment: Hago llamado a la función **directiveFunction** dentro del controlador, esta función esta ubicada dentro de una directiva "**app.directive**"; lo que necesito es que la función **directiveFunction** se me ejecute cada vez que que entre a el else donde hago el llamado:

`else {           $scope.monto = ($scope.monto + "" + num);
               // Llamada a la directiva
                $scope.dirOptions.directiveFunction();
            }`